# django_tables2 Table Meta row attributes are not displayed

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm using `django_tables2` library in my project and trying to implement a table where each row would possess a `data-item-name` attribute. My specific table is inherited from my `BaseTable` class which in its turn is inherited from `django_tables2.Table` class. Here is the code:

**page_table.py**

```
import django_tables2 as tables

from django.utils.html import format_html

from myapp.utils.base_table import BaseTable
from myapp.models import MyModel

class PageTable(BaseTable):
    item_id = tables.Column(accessor='pk')

    # This method works perfectly fine as expected
    def render_item_name(self, record):
        return format_html(
            '<span data-item-id="{0}">{1}</span>'.format(
                record.item_id,
                record.item_name
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        # When debugging this attribute is accessed only on booting up
        # And is ignored when I for example first visit or refresh the page
        row_attrs={
            'data-item-name': lambda r: r.item_name
        }
        fields = (
            'item_id',
            'item_name',
            'item_description',
            'item_price', # etc
        )
```

**base_table.py**

```
from django_tables2 import Table

class BaseTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Though the table is rendered without errors and nothing breaks up, there is no `data-item-name` attribute not on a single row in the table, although as far as I've gone through docs, it's said that declaring this property in table's metaclass is enough. Am I mistaken or is there something I missed in this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.8.17 and django-tables2 v. 1.16.0

Comment: For some reason it's working now when I changed `r` to `record` in lambda expression. Could someone give me an explanation to this? Because I'm failing to understand :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django tables use (as Django as well)  [metaclasses](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) for factoring the table classes that's the reason you see in the debugger that such lines are hitten *only on booting up* because is when the class for your table is being created.

On the other hand django-tables2 (by design) has the name `record` for the current data in the row when you're customizing row attributes.

You can read in the [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html#row-attributes):

> By default, class names odd and even are supplied to the rows, which can be customized using the row_attrs Table.Meta attribute or as argument to the constructor of Table. String-like values will just be added, callables will be called with optional keyword argument **record**, the return value will be added. For example.

Comment: thank you, that explained a lot! I guess I should read the docs more carefully.